# About entering data in CPLEX

Tags: algorithm, optimization, cplex

I have two files, one for the data and the other for the code. I defined several Tuple in the code file, and when I tried to enter the data in the data file, I received an error stating that the variable P was already defined. P is defined in the code file, but I have to enter the values in the data file.

Answer (score 0):

In the model (.mod) , in order to tell that the data will be in the .dat you should use ...

For instance, [zoodat.mod](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoodat.mod)

```
int nbKids=...;
float costBus40=...;
float costBus30=...;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
} 

execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
    {
    writeln("The minimum cost is ",cplex.getObjValue());
    writeln("We will use ",nbBus40," 40 seats buses and ",nbBus30," 30 seats buses ");
    }
```

and [zoodat.dat](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoodat.dat)

```
nbKids=300;
costBus40=500;
costBus30=400;
```

and with regards to your comments

.mod

```
int Numofpaths=1;

tuple path{string origin;string nodeA;string nodeB; string nodeC;string destination;} ;

path paths[1..Numofpaths]=...;
```

.dat

```
paths=[<"A","B","C","D","E">];
```

work fine

Comment: That's what I have in mod file"tuple path{string origin;string nodeA;string nodeB; string nodeC;string destination;} &
path paths[Numofpaths]=...; in the dat file when I enter the nodes in every path, the error stating that Path is already defined appears.

Comment: You can change paths[Numofpaths] into paths[1..Numofpaths] and that would be better

Comment: I tried it and this error appears<no range found for type int range>, I have five paths, and in each one I have origin , destination and three nodes in between

Comment: Why not opening a new question with .mod and .dat that you wrote and that give some errors ?

Comment: if you mean working on two files .mod and two files .dat just to identify errors, I have already done it, in my .dat file I have (path=[
1:origin;node1;node2;node4;destination;
2:origin;node1;node3;node5;destination;
3:origin;node2;node4;node5;destination;
4:origin;node2;node3;node5;destination;
5:origin;node3;node5;node4;destination;]

Comment: See syntax example for tuple set in .dat at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zootuplesetandassert.dat